# Why am I getting an error that there are unresolved VPC dependencies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation, devops

I'm trying to implement configuration management that meets the following criteria for an assighment:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/seis615/AnsiblePress.json

Take a quick look at the template in a text editor. Notice how the UserData property for the mgmt1 instance is configured. When CloudFormation launches this stack, it will automatically install and configure Ansible software on the management server. It’s very common to use a small amount of scripting code to bootstrap configuration management software onto a new system. Once Ansible is installed it can be used to install and configure other servers in the environment.

The CloudFormation template is missing a couple resources that you will need to add:

An application load balancer with a logical name of webserverlb which distributes HTTP (port 80) requests to the web1 and web2 instances. The health check endpoint for the load balancer should be the root (/) directory.

A db.t2.micro RDS database instance (not a cluster) running a MariaDB 10.2.21 database called wordpress located in a private VPC subnet. Use the logical name wordpressdb for the CloudFormation RDS resource. RDS and EC2 instances actually pre-date the arrival of VPCs in AWS so confusingly there are two different ways to configure these resources. You need to make sure this database instance is designed to run inside a VPC with the proper database subnet group and security group resources defined.

A security group called WebserverLbSecurityGroup which allows incoming http access from the Internet.

A security group called WordpressDbSecurityGroup which allows incoming access on the standard MySQL port from the WebServerSecurityGroup

An input parameter called DBName which will define the database name to create (default to wordpress)

An input parameter called DBUser which will be used for the database server username.

An input parameter called DBPassword which will be used for the database server password.

A stack output called wordpressDbEndpoint which shows the MariaDB instance endpoint address.

A stack output called wordpressLbEndpoint which shows the application load balancer URL.

The JSON I've configured (below) gives me the following template format error and I don't know why:

**Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [wordpressVPC] in the Resources block of the template**

```json
    {"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
      "SSMAccessRole": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [ {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": {
                     "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ]
                  },
                  "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
               } ]
            },
            "Path": "/"
         }
      },
      "SSMRolePolicies": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "ssmProperties",
            "PolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [
                 {
                   "Effect": "Allow",
                   "Action": [
                     "ssm:DescribeParameters",
                     "ssm:PutParameter",
                     "ssm:GetParameters",
                     "ssm:DeleteParameter"
                   ],
                   "Resource": {
                     "Fn::Join" : [
                       "",
                       [
                         "arn:aws:ssm:",
                         { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                         ":",
                         { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"},
                         {
                           "Fn::Join" : [
                             "",
                             [ ":parameter/", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, ".*" ]
                           ]
                         }
                       ]
                     ]
                    }
                   }
                 ]
            },
            "Roles": [ { "Ref": "SSMAccessRole" } ]
         }
      },
      "SSMInstanceProfile": {
         "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
         "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "Roles": [ { "Ref": "SSMAccessRole" } ]
         }
      },
      "web1pem" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
        "Properties" : {
          "Name" : {
            "Fn::Join" : [
              "",
              [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, ".web1pem" ]
            ]
          },
          "Type" : "String",
          "Value" : "0",
          "Description": "web1 instance private key."
        }
      },
      "web2pem" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
        "Properties" : {
          "Name" : {
            "Fn::Join" : [
              "",
              [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, ".web2pem" ]
            ]
          },
          "Type" : "String",
          "Value" : "0",
          "Description": "web2 instance private key."
        }
      },
      "wordpressVpc": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
          "Properties": {
              "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
              "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
              "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Environment",
                      "Value": "Test"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
      "publicSubnet1": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              },
              "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
               "AvailabilityZone" : {
                  "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::GetAZs" : { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }}]
                }
          }
      },
      "publicSubnet2": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              },
              "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
               "AvailabilityZone" : {
                  "Fn::Select" : [ "1", { "Fn::GetAZs" : { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }}]
                }
          }
      },
      "privateSubnet1": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              },
              "CidrBlock": "10.0.2.0/24",
              "AvailabilityZone" : {
                  "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::GetAZs" : { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }}]
                }
          }
      },
      "privateSubnet2": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              },
              "CidrBlock": "10.0.3.0/24",
              "AvailabilityZone" : {
                  "Fn::Select" : [ "1", { "Fn::GetAZs" : { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }}]
                }
          }
      },
      "web1": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "DependsOn": [
              "web1pem"
          ],
          "Properties": {
              "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
              "ImageId": {"Ref": "AMI"},
              "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Ref": "SSMInstanceProfile"
              },
              "KeyName": {
                  "Ref": "KeyName"
              },
              "NetworkInterfaces": [
                  {
                      "GroupSet": [
                          {
                              "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                          }
                      ],
                      "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                      "DeviceIndex": "0",
                      "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                      "SubnetId": {
                          "Ref": "publicSubnet1"
                      }
                  }
              ],
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": "web1"
                  }
              ],
              "UserData" : {
                "Fn::Base64" : {
                  "Fn::Join" : [
                    "", [
                      "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                      "ssh-keygen -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web1-key.pem -q -N \"\"\n",
                      "chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web1-key.pem\n",
                      "chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web1-key.pem.pub\n",
                      "PEMFILE=`cat /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web1-key.pem`\n",
                      "aws ssm put-parameter --name ", { "Ref" : "web1pem" }, " --type String --value \"${PEMFILE}\" --overwrite --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
                      "cat /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web1-key.pem.pub >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys\n",
                      "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                      "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                      "         --stack ",
                      {
                          "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      },
                      "         --resource web1 ",
                      "         --region ",
                      {
                          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
          },
          "CreationPolicy": {
              "ResourceSignal": {
                  "Timeout": "PT5M"
              }
          }
      },
      "web2": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "DependsOn": [
              "web1pem"
          ],
          "Properties": {
              "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
              "ImageId": {"Ref": "AMI"},
              "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Ref": "SSMInstanceProfile"
              },
              "KeyName": {
                  "Ref": "KeyName"
              },
              "NetworkInterfaces": [
                  {
                      "GroupSet": [
                          {
                              "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"
                          }
                      ],
                      "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                      "DeviceIndex": "0",
                      "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                      "SubnetId": {
                          "Ref": "publicSubnet2"
                      }
                  }
              ],
              "Tags": [
                  {
                      "Key": "Name",
                      "Value": "web2"
                  }
              ],
              "UserData" : {
                "Fn::Base64" : {
                  "Fn::Join" : [
                    "", [
                      "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                      "ssh-keygen -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web2-key.pem -q -N \"\"\n",
                      "chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web2-key.pem\n",
                      "chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web2-key.pem.pub\n",
                      "PEMFILE=`cat /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web2-key.pem`\n",
                      "aws ssm put-parameter --name ", { "Ref" : "web2pem" }, " --type String --value \"${PEMFILE}\" --overwrite --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },"\n",
                      "cat /home/ec2-user/.ssh/web2-key.pem.pub >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys\n",
                      "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                      "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                      "         --stack ",
                      {
                          "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                      },
                      "         --resource web2 ",
                      "         --region ",
                      {
                          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                      },
                      "\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
          },
          "CreationPolicy": {
              "ResourceSignal": {
                  "Timeout": "PT5M"
              }
          }
      },
      "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              },
              "GroupDescription": "Allow access from HTTP and SSH traffic",
              "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "80",
                      "ToPort": "80",
                      "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                  },
                  {
                      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                      "FromPort": "22",
                      "ToPort": "22",
                      "CidrIp": {"Ref": "YourIp"}
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
      "WebServerSGIngressTCP22": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
        "Metadata": {
          "Comment": "SSH ingress security rule"
        },
        "Properties" : {
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "FromPort": "22",
          "ToPort": "22",
          "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup" },
          "GroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["WebServerSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
        }
      },
      "InternetGateway": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
          "Properties": {}
      },
      "AttachGateway": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
          "Properties": {
              "InternetGatewayId": {
                  "Ref": "InternetGateway"
              },
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              }
          }
      },
      "PublicRouteTable": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
          "Properties": {
              "VpcId": {
                  "Ref": "wordpressVpc"
              }
          }
      },
      "PublicRoute": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
          "Properties": {
              "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "PublicRouteTable"
              },
              "GatewayId": {
                  "Ref": "InternetGateway"
              }
          },
          "DependsOn": [
              "InternetGateway", "AttachGateway"
          ]
      },
      "Public1RouteTableAssociation": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
          "Properties": {
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "PublicRouteTable"
              },
              "SubnetId": {
                  "Ref": "publicSubnet1"
              }
          }
      },
      "Public2RouteTableAssociation": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
          "Properties": {
              "RouteTableId": {
                  "Ref": "PublicRouteTable"
              },
              "SubnetId": {
                  "Ref": "publicSubnet2"
              }
          }
      },
      "webserverlb": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
        "Properties": {
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "webserverlbSecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "Subnets": [
                {
                    "Ref": "publicSubnet1"
                },
                {
                    "Ref": "publicSubnet2"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "webserverlb"
                }
            ]
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "webserversSecurityGroup"
        ]
      },
    "webserverlbSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "wordpressVPC"
            },
            "GroupDescription": "Allows incoming requests from port 80 via HTTP.",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "TCP",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Description": "Allows 80 from Internet"
                }
            ]
        }
      },
    "wordpressdb": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "wordpressVPC"
                },
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
                "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
                "DBName": "wordpress",
                "Engine": "mariadb",
                "EngineVersion": "10.2.21",
                "MultiAZ": 1,
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "wordpressdb"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "wordpressdbSecurityGroup"
            ]
      },
    "wordpressdbSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "wordpressVPC"
                },
                "GroupDescription": "Enable access to the db via port 3306.",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "wordpressdbSecurityGroup"
                    }
                ],
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "TCP",
                        "FromPort": "3306",
                        "ToPort": "3306",
                        "Description": "Enable HTTP access."
                    }
                ]
            }
      }
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "Name of your EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances.",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "YourIp": {
          "Description": "The current CIDR IP address of your workstation (x.x.x.x/32). http://checkip.amazonaws.com/",
          "Type": "String",
          "AllowedPattern": "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\\/(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]))$",
          "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        },
        "AMI": {
          "Description": "The EC2 instance AMI",
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "ami-00dc79254d0461090"
        },
        "DBName": {
            "Description": "Name of the database",
            "Type" : "String",
            "Default": "wordpress"
        },
        "DBUser": {
            "Default": "admin",
            "NoEcho": "false",
            "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account user name",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "1",
            "MaxLength": "16",
            "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"
          },
        "DBPassword": {
            "NoEcho": "true",
            "Description" : "The password of the database.",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "1",
            "MaxLength": "16",
            "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"
          }     
        },
    "Outputs": {
        "web1PublicIp": {
          "Value": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["web1","PublicIp"]},
          "Description": "web1 public IP"
        },
        "we2PublicIp": {
          "Value": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["web2","PublicIp"]},
          "Description": "web2 public IP"
        },
        "mgmt1PublicIp": {
            "Value": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["mgmt1","PublicIp"]},
            "Description": "mgmt1 public IP"
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CloudFormation is **case sensitive**. Your vpc resource is called `wordpressVpc`, but in some places you are using `wordpressVPC`.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

```sh
E3005 DependsOn should reference other resources at Resources/webserverlb/DependsOn/0
E1012 Ref wordpressVPC not found as a resource or parameter
E1012 Ref wordpressVPC not found as a resource or parameter
E3002 Invalid Property Resources/wordpressdb/Properties/VpcId
E3003 Property DBSecurityGroupIngress missing at Resources/wordpressdbSecurityGroup/Properties
E1012 Ref wordpressVPC not found as a resource or parameter
E3002 Invalid Property Resources/wordpressdbSecurityGroup/Properties/VpcId
E3002 Invalid Property Resources/wordpressdbSecurityGroup/Properties/SecurityGroupIngress
E1010 Invalid GetAtt mgmt1.PublicIp for resource mgmt1PublicIp
```